# Calculate $\int \log(1+\log(x))x^ndx$

Tags: integration

How to calculate the following integral?
$$\int \log(1+\log(x))x^ndx,$$
$n$ is an integer $\in N$.

Comment: Mathematica produces
$$ \frac{x^{n+1} \log (\log
   (x)+1)-e^{-n-1} \text{Ei}((n+1) (\log
   (x)+1))}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Well, for $|\log(x)| < 1$ you can use the Taylor series of $\log(1+x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\textbf{small hint}$
This was a direct result of the Mathematica output as shown by user* in the comments above. 
$$\int \log(1+\log(x))x^ndx = \int \log(\log(ex))x^ndx$$

substitute $t = ex$
we find
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \log(1+\log(x))x^ndx &=& \frac{1}{e}\int \log(\log(t))\left(\frac{t}{e}\right)^ndt \\
&=& e^{-(n+1)}\int\log(\log(t))t^ndt
\end{eqnarray}
$$
make another sub $\log t = u$
we find
$$
e^{-(n+1)}\int \log u \mathrm{e}^{(n+1)u}du
$$

using the fact
$$
\int \mathrm{e}^{cx}\ln x = \frac{1}{c}\left(\mathrm{e}^{cx}\ln |x| - \mathrm{Ei}(cx)\right)
$$
we find that with $c=n+1$ and $x = u$
$$
e^{-(n+1)}\int \log u \mathrm{e}^{(n+1)u}du = e^{-(n+1)}\frac{1}{n+1}\left(\mathrm{e}^{(n+1)u}\ln |u| - \mathrm{Ei}[(n-1)u]\right)
$$
and you should be able to finish off with subbing in $u = 1+ \log(x)$

Comment: No I was just seeing that myself..I have messed up that exponential. I will fix it now. Thank you.

Comment: @Michael hopefully it is corrected now. Thank you again.

Comment: I think that the difficult part is $$\int \mathrm{e}^{cx}\ln x = \frac{1}{c}\left(\mathrm{e}^{cx}\ln |x| - \mathrm{Ei}(cx)\right)$$ Do you agree ?

Comment: How do you mean? is it with regards to "$\textbf{small hint}$"?. Or was it the wrong approach?

Comment: Not at all; your work is really good. I was just commenting the part I felt the most difficult (to me !!). Thanks for your answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: I would like to point it's the posters like yourself and the other well respected guys on here that I learn from. How I solve Integrals like these is a direct result from what I learn on this forum. So thank you :).

Comment: I hope I am not too much respected ! Be sure that I learnt from you and this post is an example. Continue doing a so good work (by the way : in which university are you in London ?). I thank you ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you (returning a compliment you said on one of my other posts) your comment means a lot. As for university I have finished now, but it was not in London but at warwick uni. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I think it can be solved by this way
$$\int \ln(1+\ln x)x^n dx$$
using integration by parts
$$u=\ln(1+\ln x)\Rightarrow
du=\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{1+\ln x}dx=\frac{dx}{x(1+\ln x)}\\
dv=x^ndx\Rightarrow v=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
\int \ln(1+\ln x)x^n dx=\ln(1+\ln x)\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\int\frac{x^n}{1+\ln x}dx=\\
\frac{1}{n+1}\left[\ln(1+\ln x)x^{n+1}-\int\frac{x^n}{1+\ln x}dx\right]=\\
\frac{1}{n+1}\left[\ln(1+\ln x)x^{n+1}-\int\frac{x^n}{\ln ex}dx\right]$$
then
$$\int\frac{x^n}{\ln ex}dx\\
u=\ln ex\\
e^u=ex\Rightarrow x=e^{u-1}\\
du=\frac{dx}{x}\Rightarrow dx=xdu=e^{u-1}du\\
\int\frac{x^n}{\ln ex}dx=\int\frac{(e^{u-1})^n}{u}e^{u-1}du=\int\frac{e^{nu-n}e^{u-1}}{u}du=\\
\int\frac{e^{(n+1)u}e^{-(n+1)}}{u}du=e^{-(n+1)}\int\frac{e^{(n+1)u}}{u}du=\\
e^{-(n+1)}\text{Ei}[(n+1)u]=e^{-(n+1)}\text{Ei}[(n+1)\ln ex]=e^{-(n+1)}\text{Ei}[(n+1)(1+\ln x)]$$
which gives
$$\frac{\ln(1+\ln x)x^{n+1}-e^{-(n+1)}\text{Ei}[(n+1)(1+\ln x)]}{n+1}$$

Comment: I like the fact you showed all the steps :) +1